# Missing buttons for logs, pod etc on components of pipeline runs in KFP UI

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

We have set up an on-prem Kubeflow 1.7 installation and are trying out Kubeflow Pipelines v2.x.
When executing a run on the provided pipeline "[Tutorial] Data passing in python components", all the components expose quite a lot of tabs, including pod logs:
[image: Information tabs visible on a run component of the example pipeline]

However, when we create a pipeline of our own with KFP SDK v2 (I don't know if v1 would solve the issue since v1 pipelines are rejected due to the wrong format) and issue runs of that pipeline, the component information looks like this:
[image: Reduced information tabs visible on a run component of our own pipeline]

As you can see, most of the information tabs are missing. We would at least need the `Logs` button. Right now, users need `kubectl` access to the cluster to see what went wrong with their component.

How can we activate the tabs shown for runs on the example pipeline?
At the very least, how can we view the component pod logs in the Kubeflow Dashboard?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Short version: Install Kfp >= v2.0.0 (not alpha or beta but release version).

Longer version: After quite some experimentation and research I have a better understanding now. Lessons learned:

1. Kubeflow 1.7 comes with an alpha version of Kfp where some functionality is just missing, including the "Logs" tab of pipeline components.
2. Updating Kfp to v2.0.0 release version fixes this (and other) issue(s).
3. Kfp v1 pipelines still work with Kfp 2.0. You just have to take care to install the right Python SDK library when creating pipelines with the SDK (currently kfp==v1.8.22 for v1 pipelines and kfp==2.1.2 (or just leave out the version) for v2 pipelines)
4. Yes, v1 pipelines show all the tabs in the screenshot. v2 pipelines will not show all those tabs but that is by design.